# Problema al automatizar mysqldump usando cron

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7, cron, crontab

Estoy intentando automatizar mis copias de seguridad encriptadas usando cron.

Tengo un comando tal que así:

```
mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysqldump.cnf \
    --routines --events --triggers --single-transaction database | \
    openssl smime -encrypt -binary -text -aes256 -out database.sql.enc -outform DER /home/mysqldump-secure.pub.pem
```

Todo funciona correctamente si lo ejecuto en la línea de comandos.
También si lanzo el fichero .sh que lo contiene, en este caso se llama **cron.sh**

**./cron.sh**

Sin embargo cron lo ejecuta y me da el siguiente error:

Este es el contenido al hacer un **crontab -e**

*16 21 * * *  /home/cron.sh*

El error que obtengo al inspeccionar lo siguiente:

```
cat /var/spool/mail/root

Error opening recipient certificate file mysqldump-secure.pub.pem
139929931360144:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:402:fopen('mysqldump-secure.pub.pem','r')
139929931360144:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:404:
unable to load certificate mysqldump: Got errno 32 on write
```

El certificado está en el mismo directorio que el el fichero **cron.sh**
He modificado los permisos del certificado público a **777** a ver si tenía que ver, pero no hay manera.

Linux Centos 7 x64

Alguna sugerencia??

Gracias

Comment: ¿Ya revisaste que 1) El header del script que lo corre, contenga: `#!/bin/bash`. 2) antes de correr el comando, hacer un `cd` hacía la carpeta que quieres que funcione como contexto (o mejor usa rutas absolutas para todo), 3) Revisar si en tu script no tienes un tipo o el nombre del archivo ".pem" sea ligeramente diferente o ponerlo en un lugar mas accesible?

Comment: Cuando ejecuto ./cron.sh funciona correctamente, genera el fichero encriptado sin problemas. Luego lo desencripto y es correcto. La cosa es que ahora he reducido el fichero sola al mysqldump  mysqldump  --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysqldump.cnf  --routines --events --triggers --single-transaction database > database y sigue sin funcionar cuando lo lanzo con el cron.  He añadido una linea para generar un fichero (touch ficherotest) a ver si es que no funciona, pero si que me crea este fichero. No entiendo nada